# Getting null in debugger while using stringWithFormat

Tags: ios, objective-c, null, xcode8, stringwithformat

[image: (null) while converting double to NSString using stringWithFormat]

I am using simply `stringWithFormat` to get the string value of double using `%f`. But I am getting `null`. If I use `NSString *myString = [NSNumber stringValue];` it works. What is wrong with code shown in attached screenshot? [image: With NSLog]

This is actual production code. and because of this issue some time (very rare) I get crash. The fabric crash log shows that adding null value to NSDictionary causing crash. as I am using modern objective C. my question is "How `stringWithFormat` works?"

Comment: What does the `NSLog` statement actually print?

Comment: Please post Code here instead of screen shot.

Comment: @rmaddy NSLog printing actual value. but in debug window it is showing **null**. `(NSTaggedPointerString *) (null)`

Comment: Your code is fine, the debugger is buggy. I'd try right-clicking on the variable (in the lower pane of the debugger) and selecting `Print Description of "whatever variable"` or typing `po variable` in the debugger console.

Comment: @Hiteshsurani I update in in question.

Comment: @ManishNahar Do not post code in comments. Update your question. But in this case, there is no reason to post your code.

Comment: Please make sure your project should be run in Debug mode.

Comment: @Hiteshsurani yes it is in debug mode only. it is not consistent. the problem is that this similar crash i am facing in published App.

Answer (score 0):

In second Screen shot, You have one unused code.

**Please remove this line Then, It will work fine.**

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",number];
```

Hope you it will work for you.

Comment: Working or not?

Comment: As i said it is rare issue and could be edge case. it is nothing to do with removing unused code. The actual issue lies with `stringWithFormat` i wanted to know the actual cause of getting `null`